# Using rainbow tables to obtain the first 7 characters of a windows password(LM/NTLMv1)

Tags: windows, ntlm, rainbow-table

I am trying to understand how an attacker is able to use the [halflm challenge](https://freerainbowtables.com/) rainbow table to obtain the first 7 characters of a windows password that was used to authenticate a user using LM/NTLMv1. To help you understand my confusion, consider this illustrative example:

- Suppose a user(`U`) intends to authenticate on a server `S`.
- An attacker(`A`) uses a Mitm attack to pretend to be the `S`.
- Then `U` will send a LM response to the fixed challenge(`C`) string sent by the attacker.

Am I correct in my understanding that:

- `A` can create a rainbow table(`R`) whose key is the first 8 characters of the challenge response and whose value is the first 7 characters of the Lanman hash(stored locally in the SAM file).
- obtaining the first 7 characters of the lanman hash is a matter of performing a lookup on `R`.

My Question:
How does the attacker convert the first 7 characters of the lanman hash to the first 7 characters of the password? The reason I ask is because, to my understanding computing the lanman hash is done by splitting the password into 2 7 character blocks and then using each block to obtain 8 bytes of the lanman hash.

A roundabout way of asking my question is:
Wouldnt the attacker need the first 8 bytes of the lanman hash to compute the first 7 characters of the password? If so then how does the attacker obtain the 8th character in the lanman hash(the first 7 are trivial if my understanding is right).